# It is possible to install Exchange Server on a single W2008 server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange-2007

Can I install Exchange 2007 onto a Windows 2008 single server, which will be the only server in the LAN? I'm guessing this server will also have the AD on it, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can, it is perfectly possible. Its not a great Idea to have Exchange and AD on the same machine, it makes your network a little less secure - if Exchange is compromised then its likely your AD infrastructure will be as well.

However MS do it with their SBS product and many many small business do it.

Also, if you using server 2008, you must use Exchange 2007 Sp1

Comment: Can i use any version of W2008 server?

Comment: You can install it on Standard, Enterprise and Datacenter, not the Web Edition

Comment: one followup note: in addition to security issues, having AD and Exchange on the same box makes disaster recovery quite a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 4):

For licensing purposes, I would strongly suggest looking at SBS - it's a lot cheaper and Microsoft have pre-configured the various applications to share the resources on the server properly.

The only real limitations of SBS are (a) all the FSMO roles have to be on the SBS server and (b) you can't have more than 75 users.

Comment: +1 SBS is neat - though the 2008 version stripped away half of the features and doubled the price, it's still a good deal.

Comment: Don't forget Essential Business Server, which supports up to 300 clients and splits the roles. http://www.microsoft.com/ebs/en/us/default.aspx

Comment: @Oskar, I think one sign of how good a deal SBS2003 was is that half the features at twice the price is still a really good deal.

And 2008 really isn't that cut back from 2003; the only thing they really cut was ISA, which, frankly was stupid on a single-server solution anyway; firewalls really should be a dedicated box.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can - I've done it personally, on both 2003 and 2008.

Couple things to consider:

- RAM requirements are fairly steep for a single server install.  Be sure to look into this beforehand to make sure your server can handle the demand of running Exchange, AD, etc.  Check out [this link](http://msexchangeteam.com/archive/2006/09/25/428994.aspx) for more details.
- If you're using 2008, you'll need to download [Exchange 2007 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=44C66AD6-F185-4A1D-A9AB-473C1188954C&displaylang=en) and install from that, as it won't install from your disc.

Good luck!

Comment: install the full product, from a service pack? or is the full product got the sp slipstreamed?

Comment: Full product installs from the service pack.